# Decrease size by a smaller and smaller value

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm looking for a function to decrease a scale in size but to a certain smallest size which it can't practically reach. So at first the number is 1. The next step might get to 0.9 and the next 0.85 and so on. What's the best way to achieve this?

Is perhaps log(i) appropriate in some form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to decrease the value of $\alpha$  upto $\beta$. The following function will work.

> $$y=\beta \cdot \left(1+\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1\right)a^{-bx}\right)$$

Here $a,b \in \mathbb{ R^+}$ are fixed constants with $a>1$.

Comment: It seems to work great! But why not write it as $y = \beta + \frac{\alpha - \beta}{a^{bx}}$?

Comment: Oh! And $a$ has to be greater than $1$

Comment: @ChristofferAB What you have written in your first comment, it is just the simplification of the expression written in the answer, and yes, I forgot to write $a>1$.It is must.

Answer (score 0):

One choice would be $\frac 12 + \frac 1{2n}$ which starts at $1$ and decreases toward $\frac 12$.  It should be clear how to choose the constants to get the start and asymptote you want.